# Requests "Too Many Requests"

Tags: python, web, python-requests

I'm trying to get HTML code for a Scratch website (specifically http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/804808870) and I have the following code:

```
import requests

url = requests.get("http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/804808870")
htmltext = url.text
print(htmltext)
```

But when I run the code it returns this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>429 Too many requests</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 429 Too many requests</h1>
    <p>Too many requests</p>
    <h3>Error 54113</h3>
    <p>Details: cache-fty21342-FTY 1685391858 353868615</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried looking this up on Google and it said I was sending too may requests too quickly, but this happened the first time I tried and waiting doesn't help. How do I fix this, and is there any other way to do that kind of thing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where are you running this code?  On your own computer, or on a cloud host?